# Establishing significance of crime statistics variation in a changing population over time

Tags: statistical-significance, inference, p-value, chi-squared-test

On the planet Zorblax, there are 2 ethnic groups, one much larger in number than the other.

The National Statistics Body of Zorblax wants to determine, with significance, if one group commits a disproportionate amount of theft. The data is grouped by year, as follows:

| Ethnic group info | 2001 | 2002 | 2003 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Thefts by group A | 500 | 550 | 700 |
| Population of group A | 100000 | 110000 | 120000 |
| Thefts by group B | 10 | 5 | 20 |
| Population of group B | 1000 | 800 | 1100 |

Analysing this data presents some challenges. The number of data points in the B group is smaller, so harder to get a good significance.

However, if you combine the B data together from multiple years, maybe there is enough data to make an inference? But with the changing population it becomes hard to know the right way to combine the data, and hard to choose the right test.

The question is: What is the right way to combine the data across years from group B, in such a way as you can get additional statistical power from the increased number of data points? And after doing this, which test should you apply?

For a static population, chi-square for homogeneity might make sense, but how could you apply this across years with different population sizes? Also, many inviduals in the populations are the same individuals across the years, but many are not. Does that matter?